# How to make a custom image file form with zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form-element

How can i make a custom image file by extending the zend form element ? The output in html is like below:

```
<div class="image-file-wrapper">
     <img src="yourimagepath" />
     <br />
     <input id="image-file" name="image-file" type="file" />
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

My custom form element

```
class Engine_Form_Element_ImageFile extends Zend_Form_Element_File {
public $helper = 'FormImageFile';

protected $_image;

public function setImage($src) {
    $this->_image = $src;

    return $this;    
}

public function loadDefaultDecorators() {
    if($this->loadDefaultDecoratorsIsDisabled()) {
        return;
    }

    $decorators = $this->getDecorators();

    if(empty($decorators)) {
        $this->addDecorator('ViewHelper');
        Engine_Form::addDefaultDecorators($this);
    }
}
}
```

My custom view helper:

```
class Engine_View_Helper_FormImageFile extends Zend_View_Helper_FormElement {
public function formImageFile($name, $value = null, $attribs = null, $options = null) {
    return '<div class="image-file-wrapper"><img src="test.png" /><input type="file" /></div>';    
}    
}
```

When i try to add it,

```
$this->addElement('ImageFile', 'imageFile', array('label' => 'Test Image'));
```

the error occured:

```
Warning: Exception caught by form: No file decorator found... unable to render file element Stack Trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\NEOBBS_v6\library\Zend\Form\Decorator\FormElements.php(101): Zend_Form_Element_File->render() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\NEOBBS_v6\library\Zend\Form.php(2904): Zend_Form_Decorator_FormElements->render('') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\NEOBBS_v6\library\Zend\Form.php(2920): Zend_Form->render() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\NEOBBS_v6\application\themes\admin\settings.phtml(8): Zend_Form->__toString() #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\NEOBBS_v6\library\Zend\View.php(108): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\NEOBBS_v6\library\Zend\View\Abstract.php(880): Zend_View->_run('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\NEOBBS_v6\library\Zend\Controller\Action\Helper\ViewRenderer.php(897): Zend_View_Abstract->render('settings.phtml') #7 C:\xampp\htdocs\NEOBBS_v6\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php(243): Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_ViewRenderer->renderScript('settings.phtml', NULL) #8 C:\xampp\htdocs\NEOBBS_v6\application\modules\admin\contr in C:\xampp\htdocs\NEOBBS_v6\library\Zend\Form.php on line 2925
```

How do i fix it ?

Thanks in advance,

Brian

Answer (score 0):

Use Zend_Form_Decorator_ViewScript. For details: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.standardDecorators.html#zend.form.standardDecorators.viewScript

Comment: yeah but i always get error: Warning: Exception caught by form: Plugin by name 'FormImageFile' was not found in the registry; used paths: